# Python bot script with CV2 library

Tags: python, opencv

please can you help me troubleshoot this code, just started to learn and can't find the solution. Thanks
I did many times some changes but still having this problem
This script is for fishing in a game with a recognize item on a picture and then run some functions

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
from mss.windows import MSS as mss

template = cv2.imread("/Users/vk/Desktop/bot_screen/1.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
w, h, = template.shape[::-1]

color_yellow = (0, 255, 255)

mon = {'top': 80, 'left': 350, 'width': 100, 'height': 100}

def process_image(original_image):

    processed_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    processed_image = cv2.Canny(processed_image, threshold1=200, threshold2=300)
    return processed_image

def ss():
    op = 1
    with mss.mss() as sct:

        monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 800, "height": 640}

        while "Screen capturing":
            last_time = time.time()

            img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))


            gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_frame, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            loc = np.where(res >= 0.8)
            op += 1
            print(op)
            for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
                for p in img:
                    pts = (pt[0],pt[1])
                    x = (pt[0])
                    y = (pt[1])
                    print(x)
                    if 100 < x < 490:
                            pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
                            time.sleep(2)
                            pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
                            x = 0
                            break
                    else:
                            continue
                    break
                else:
                        continue
                break
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            if op > 35:
                return

def screen_record():
    sct = mss.mss()
    last_time = time.time()

    while(True):
        img = sct.grab(mon)
        print('loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - last_time))
        last_time = time.time()

        img = np.array(img)
        processed_image = process_image(img)
        mean = np.mean(processed_image)
        print('mean = ', mean)

        if mean <= float(0.11):
            print('SSSSSSSS ')
            pyautogui.click(button='left')
            break
            return
        else:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            continue
        return
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

while "1":
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(431,175,duration=1)
    pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
    pyautogui.moveTo(450,200,duration=1)
    pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
    time.sleep(2)
    screen_record()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ss()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l21I.png)
Error in the picture

Answer (score 0):

You're setting it to `mss.mss()`, which doesn't exist. When I used the same import as you, just doing `sct = mss()` worked fine.